# Using NSKeyedArchiver and NSData to send UIImage over bluetooth

Tags: iphone, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

I was wondering if it is possible to send a UIImage over bluetooth after encoding it into a NSMutableData using NSKeyedArchiver. This is what I had in mind:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:[UIImage imageNamed:"test.png" forKey:kImageKey];

[archiver finishEncoding];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot archive `UIImage` instances like that. You will have to create an external representation first, like PNG or JPG. You can do that with for example the `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` function. It will return an `NSData` instance containing the compressed image in PNG format. That `NSData` instance can be used with NSArchiving.

Comment: I guess I would have known this if I'd simply looked at the class reference for UIImage. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to subclass NSObject to create a class that contains an image, name, number etc. and archive that?

Comment: Yes. But using a dictionary is also perfectly fine I think. And it is somewhat safer if you have two different versions of the app. Or at least easier to deal with.

Comment: Not true. UIImage conforms to NSSecureCoding, which inherits from NSCoding so it definitely can be encoded this way.

Comment: @Mike Was this always the case? My answer is from 5 years ago. Can't remember what the SDK looked like back then.

Comment: I don't think you want to use Archiving actually. Because it archives the pixel buffer it seems. Not the much more compact PNG or JPG representation.

Comment: It's probably changed since then, now that I think about it. So your answer was correct but there should be someway to update it. Is there a way to mark stackoverflow questions/answers as deprecated or something similar?